# PyQt5: Why does QPushButton.setDefault() ignore spacebar but work for enter/return?

Tags: pyqt5, qpushbutton, qdialog

I have a modal with two buttons, one `Accept` and one `Cancel`.
I set the cancel button to be the default with `.setDefault()` and `.setAutoDefault()`

Pressing return activates the cancel-button, but when I press spacebar the accept-button is activated.

Why is the application/accept-button ignoring the defaultness-configuration and activates on spacebar presses rather than the cancel button? It seems like the accept-button has focus or something despite there being a different default.
Why would the default not have focus?

If I call `cancel_button.setFocus()` just before showing the modal (but not earlier than that), even the spacebar will activate the Cancel-button instead of the Acccept-button, so that solves the underlying problem.

The question is why spacebar and enter do not both activate the default button.

### Minimal example:

The modal shows up when the program is run, as well as when the user presses `X`.
Press `ctrl+Q` to close the application.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, \
                            QWidget, QShortcut, QDialog, QPushButton

class Modal(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(QSize(600, 300))
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.setWindowModality(True)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        buttons = self.create_buttons()
        layout.addWidget(buttons)
        # This sets focus (when pressing spacebar), and makes the modal work as expected.
        # The question is why is this needed to make spacebar default to activating Cancel?
        # Why is spacebar activating Accept by default without this line?:
        #self.cancel_button.setFocus()

    def create_buttons(self):
        button_groupbox = QGroupBox()
        button_box_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_groupbox.setLayout(button_box_layout)

        # Despite setting the defaultness, pressing spacebar still activates the accept-button.
        # Pressing return activates the cancel-button, however, and is expected behaviour.
        # Why is the Accept-button being activated when space is pressed?
        accept_button = QPushButton("Accept")
        accept_button.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        accept_button.setDefault(False)
        accept_button.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.accept_button = accept_button

        cancel_button = QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        cancel_button.setDefault(True)
        cancel_button.setAutoDefault(True)
        self.cancel_button = cancel_button

        # This does not set focus (when pressing spacebar), maybe because it has not been added yet?
        #cancel_button.setFocus()

        button_box_layout.addWidget(accept_button)
        button_box_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)
        return button_groupbox

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+Q"), self)
        shortcut.activated.connect(app.quit)

        shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("X"), self)
        shortcut.activated.connect(self.run_modal)

        self.resize(QSize(800, 600))
        self.show()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        self.run_modal()

    def run_modal(self):
        self.modal = Modal(self)
        self.modal.finished.connect(self.modal_finished)
        self.modal.show()

    def modal_finished(self, result):
        if result == 0:
            print("CANCEL")
        elif result == 1:
            print("ACCEPT")
        else:
            raise Exception("BAD RESULT")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As explained in the [`default`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) property documentation: "A button with this property set to true [...] will automatically be pressed when the user presses enter. [...] Buttons can always be clicked from the keyboard by pressing Spacebar **when the button has focus**.". Besides, remove that `run_modal()` from the `paintEvent()`: a paint function should **always** and **only** paint, not do anything else.

Comment: I tried putting it under `showEvent()`, but the modal ended up in the wrong position (perhaps because the parent did not have its position ready at that point).

Comment: Use a `QTimer.singleShot`, doing that in the paintEvent is just wrong.

Comment: It actually looks like the Cancel button has focus, though -- I do not see any indication the Accept button has focus.

Comment: @Meowf Well, the accept-button clearly *does* have the focus, since pressing the spacebar activates it. Also, pressing tab will move the focus *from* the accept-button *to* the cancel-button (which will then show a focus-rectangle). Conclusion: if you don't explicitly set a focus-widget yourself, [Qt will just pick one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/focus.html#the-user-moves-the-focus-to-this-window).

Comment: The cancel button already has the focus rectangle before I press tab though?

Comment: @Meowf I can't reproduce that. For me, when the cancel-button is explictly given the focus (with or without a focus-rectangle), pressing space activates it. I only tested on Linux, though. Maybe the behaviour is different/buggy on other platforms.

Comment: I guess what I am saying is the accept button does not have the focus rectangle prior to pressing spacebar.

Comment: @Meowf You ask: "Why is the accept-button ignoring spacebar presses?", maybe you meant the opposite? Right now your code (upon showing and doing anything else) correctly "clicks" on the "Accept" button with the space bar and "Cancel" with return. Be aware, though, that using the return key to *cancel* is not a very good idea from the UX perspective. Can you also write the output of `print(app.style().objectName())` and your current OS?

Comment: Oh right, I probably meant "why is the application ignoring spacebar presses with respect to the default action/button". The output is `qt5ct-style` and I am on Linux/X11. Maybe clicking on the accept-button is correct, but the accept button lacks the blue focus rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, widgets receive focus based on the order in which they are added to a parent. When the *top level* window is shown, the first widget that accepts focus, following the order above, will receive input focus, meaning that *any* keyboard event will be sent to that widget first.

Note that when widgets are added to a layout, but were *not* created with the parent used for that layout, then the order follows that of the layout insertion.

The [`default`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) property of QPushButtons, instead will "press" the button whenever the top level widget receives the <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys are pressed, no matter of the current *focused* widget, **and** as long as the focused widget does *not* handle those keys.

In your case, the currently focused widget is the "Accept" button (since it's the first that has been added to the window), which results in the counter-intuitive behavior you're seeing.

If you want the cancel button to react to both Return/Enter keys (no matter what is the focused widget) *and* the space bar upon showing, then you have to explicitly call `setFocus()`. But there's a catch: since `setFocus()` sets the focus on a widget in the active window, it can only work as long as that widget already belongs to that window.

In your case, the `cancel_button.setFocus()` call done within `create_buttons` won't work because, at that point, the button doesn't belong to the top level window *yet*.
It *does* work when you do that *after* `layout.addWidget(buttons)`, because *then* the button is part of the window.

So, considering the above:

- if you want to set the focus on a widget, that widget *must* already belong to the top level widget *before* calling `setFocus()`;
- the `default` button will *always* be triggered upon Return/Enter keypress even if *another* button has focus;

With your current code, you either do what you already found out (using `setFocus()` on the instance attribute *after* adding the widget), or use a basic QTimer in the `create_buttons` function:

```
QTimer.singleShot(0, cancel_button.setFocus)
```

Note that:

- while creating separate functions can help you to better organize your code, having a separate function that is just called *once* is often unnecessary (other than misleading and forcing the creation of instance attributes where they're not actually necessary); just separate code blocks with empty lines, unless those functions can be overridden by further subclasses;
- setting a "Cancel" button that can be activated by Return/Enter is not a very good idea, as those keys are generally used for "Accept/Apply/Commit/Write/etc." purposes;
- if you want to show a dialog as soon as its parent is shown, you shall only use a QTimer: `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.run_modal)`; the paint event is certainly not a viable option (paint events occur very, *very* often, and in some systems even when the widget loses focus, which can cause recursion), nor is the `showEvent()` since that could happen when switching virtual desktops or unminimizing the window;